# How to successfully update HTML Audio Player source in .then function in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, aws-lambda

I am setting up a Serverless website, and one of the backend Lambda functions is to construct an S3 url, which the frontend uses to update the source of an audio player embedded in the HTML.

As the frontend must wait for the Lambda function to finish and return a functioning URL, the audio player's source is updated within a .then function:

```
  var accessKey = getURLVars()["AccessKey"];
  var audioPlayer = document.getElementById('audioURL');

  // Handle when the user enters a key into the form
  function handleKey() {
    var url = "";

    fetch(apiBaseURL+"/getFileURL", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        key: accessKey,
      })
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
      if (json.url === "not_found") {
        // The file was not found
        console.log("File not found");
        .....
      } else {
        // The file was found, update the elements to the new URL
        url = json.url;
        console.log(url);

        audioPlayer.src = url;

        .....
      }
    });
  }
```

The audio player:

```
  <audio controls>
    <source id='audioURL' type="audio/mp3" src=""></source>
    Your browser does not support this audio player.
  </audio>
```

The lambda function returns a valid url, and inspecting the audio element in Chrome shows that its source has been updated, however the audio player will not play. Further, the audio player updates its source and is playable in Microsoft Edge, but not in Chrome.

Is there something else I need to do to get the player working in Chrome, or do I need to use a different audio player?

Comment: If it plays in one browser but not another, it might depend precisely what the audio file is, and whether it matches the preset mime type you've specified: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats . Have you tried any other browsers? Are there any console errors?

Comment: I just tried Chrome and Edge, and there are no console errors anywhere. However, I believe we found the problem, it seems that Chrome does not automatically reload the audio player when the source changes, at least not in this case.

Answer (score 2):

> *"It seems that when the audio player's source changes, Chrome does not reload the audio player, and as such the audio player must be manually loaded after the source changes."*

Whenever an audio or video tag/object changes src the [.load()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) method should be invoked.

```js
...
} else {
  // The file was found, update the elements to the new URL
  url = json.url;
  console.log(url);
  audioPlayer.src = url;
  audioPlayer.load(); // Whenever an audio or video tag/object changes src the .load() method should be invoked.

  .....
}...
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when the audio player's source changes, Chrome does not reload the audio player, and as such the audio player must be manually loaded after the source changes.

Comment: No need for manual loading, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929856/2813224)

Comment: Right, by manually loading I meant calling the load function. Still odd to me that Chrome in particular had this issue, and only in this niche circumstance.

Comment: I believe that's the standard behavior as per [**HTMLMediaElement API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement)